# Python AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute '_getContents'

Tags: python

I'am trying to remove the watermark from the PDF by using a python code and the code that i am running is
I am using  `PyMuPDF` and have used `fitz` library.

```
def remove_img_on_pdf(idoc, page):
    #image list
    img_list = idoc.getPageImageList(page)
    con_list = idoc[page]._getContents()


    # xref 274 is the only /Contents object of the page (could be
    for i in con_list:
        c = idoc._getXrefStream(i) # read the stream source
        #print(c)
        if c != None:
            for v in img_list:
                
                arr = bytes(v[7], 'utf-8')
                r = c.find(arr) # try find the image display command
                if r != -1:
                    cnew = c.replace(arr, b"")
                    idoc._updateStream(i, cnew)
                    c = idoc._getXrefStream(i)
    return idoc




doc=fitz.open('ELN_Mod3AzDOCUMENTS.PDF')
rdoc = remove_img_on_pdf(doc, 0) #first page
rdoc.save('no_img_example.PDF')
```

I get this error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "watermark.py", line 27, in <module>
    rdoc = remove_img_on_pdf(doc, 0) #first page
  File "watermark.py", line 5, in remove_img_on_pdf
    con_list = idoc[page]._getContents()
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute '_getContents'
```

Please help me find out a solution out of this, thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that a `Page` object must have that attribute?

Comment: to know the difference between an image and a text..

Comment: Please post the library you're using. I assume `idoc` is a `list`. If so, the error basically means that object of `idoc` at index `0` do not have an attribute named `_getContents`. There can be multiple reasons for this. One can only help if you post the full details.

Comment: I've used PyMuPDF, fitz library here

Comment: try `print(dir(idoc[page]))` to see the available attributes for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function have some strange methods such as `_getContents`, `_getXrefStream` and `_updateStream`, maybe they are deprecated or somthing, but here is working code for solving your problem:

```
import fitz


def remove_img_on_pdf(idoc, page):
    img_list = idoc.getPageImageList(page)
    con_list = idoc[page].get_contents()

    for i in con_list:
        c = idoc.xref_stream(i)
        if c != None:
            for v in img_list:
                arr = bytes(v[7], 'utf-8')
                r = c.find(arr)
                if r != -1:
                    cnew = c.replace(arr, b"")
                    idoc.update_stream(i, cnew)
                    c = idoc.xref_stream(i)
    return idoc


doc = fitz.open('ELN_Mod3AzDOCUMENTS.PDF')
rdoc = remove_img_on_pdf(doc, 0)
rdoc.save('no_img_example.PDF')
```

As you can see, I've used another methods instead of non-working ones. Also, here is [documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for `PyMuPDF`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code works perfectly.. can you just tip me how to iterate through all the pages in the pdf and remove the images from them too, thank you

Comment: ```for i in range(doc.page_count): rdoc = remove_img_on_pdf(doc, i)
    rdoc.save('no_img_example.pdf')```

Answer (score 0):

Ïf you print dir(idoc[0]) , you see a list of attributes. you should use idoc[page].get_contents() instead.